# Pandas - consolidate two rows in one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` like this, where `home_dummy` 0 is a binary for 'Away' and 1 for 'home'.

1. If the team scored 1 'G' at 1, it scored 1 'Home'.
2. If the team scored 0 'G' at 0, it scored 0 'Away'.

I show one example, but there are many other matches.

```
            team       opponent   home_dummy  G
0     Athlético-PR       Flamengo          0  1
...
20    Athlético-PR       Flamengo          1  0
...
190       Flamengo   Athlético-PR          0  3
...
121       Flamengo   Athlético-PR          1  2
```

How do I end up with a table where the match results (Goals Home vs Goals Away) are expressed in two rows only, like this:

```
            team        opponent   HomeG AwayG
...
0       Flamengo   Athlético-PR     2     1
1       Athlético-PR   Flamengo     0     3
```

---

Note:

In a regular tournament, teams face each other two times, each one playing home once, and once away.

Comment: Can the same team play the same opponent multiple times in this dataframe? If so how do you want to handle those cases?

Comment: they play two times, each one playing home once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach.  First, convert the original data to a data frame:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''            team       opponent   home_dummy  G
0     Athlético-PR       Flamengo          0  1
20    Athlético-PR       Flamengo          1  0
190       Flamengo   Athlético-PR          0  3
121       Flamengo   Athlético-PR          1  2
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
```

Now create home and an away data frames, then join them:

```
t_home = (df.loc[ df['home_dummy'] == 1, ['team', 'opponent', 'G']]
          .rename(columns={'G': 'HomeG'})
          .copy())

# reverse team and opponent
t_away = (df.loc[ df['home_dummy'] == 0, ['team', 'opponent', 'G']]
          .rename(columns={'G': 'AwayG', 'team': 'opponent', 'opponent': 'team'})
          .copy())

result = (pd.merge(t_home, t_away, how='inner', 
                   left_on=['team', 'opponent'], right_on=['team', 'opponent']))
print(result)

           team      opponent  HomeG  AwayG
0  Athlético-PR      Flamengo      0      3
1      Flamengo  Athlético-PR      2      1
```

The sort order is different than the expected answer; not sure if that's relevant.